# Laravel belongs to many by two intermediate tables?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

Hi guys I have to create many to many relationship but through a another table. but laravel `BelongsToMany` give only 1 intermediate table relation
here table structure:

```
features Table:
+----+-----------+
| id | text      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | feature 1 |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | feature 2 |
+----+-----------+

feature_values table:
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | feature_id | text  |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 1  | 1          | val 1 |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 2  | 1          | val 2 |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 3  | 2          | val 3 |
+----+-----------+-------+

products table: 
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | tv    |
+----+-------+
| 2  | phone |
+----+-------+

product_features table:
+----+------------+------------+
| id | product_id | feature_id |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1          | 1          |
+----+------------+------------+
| 2  | 2          | 1          |
+----+------------+------------+
| 3  | 2          | 2          |
+----+------------+------------+

product_feature_values table:

+----+--------------------+------------------+
| id | product_feature_id | feature_value_id |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| 1  | 1                  | 1                |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| 2  | 2                  | 1                |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| 3  | 2                  | 2                |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
```

**I'm trying to create a relationship between `feature_values` and and `products` through `product_feature_values` and `product_features` for get `product` by `feature_values`.**

I know data can obtain by joining tables, but I looking for a solution that using by laravel model relationships

thank you.

I tried like this

```
class FeatureValue extends Model
{
   
    public function products()
    {
        return  $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'product_feature_values')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, that Laravel didn't offer that out-of the box. But there's a package called [`staudenmeir/belongs-to-through`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through) that does.

Comment: I will check . thank you. is this give same features as level relationships?

Comment: Yep, it only extends the functionality but works almost the same.